# Sitecore forms with Sitecore Commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-forms, commerce-engine, commerce-catalog

Is it possible to use Sitecore forms inside Sitecore commerce 9.2? Is there someone who has done it.

Any examples or suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: your question is too broad. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Lets say i want to insert a sitecore form with custom submit method in the checkout page. Is it possible to do it ?@VladIobagiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is possible to integrate Sitecore form into a commerce page like a checkout page.

Commerce Pages are normal pages in Sitecore and you can add any rendering to them.

To add a  rendering form to a page you need to follow this page: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html

For example I added a form into Delivery page.

You should be really careful what kind of forms you are adding to commerce pages, because you don't want to interrupt users from purchasing products.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added Sitecore form in the commerce page just like yours but I am getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" error on every sitecore form field. did you have any error like this?